# How to get level up directory when using level up symbol .. , ../.. , .. n-level up in bash script

Tags: bash, centos

I have a simple script to demonstrate this question called getpath.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# getpath.sh

path="$1"
if [ -z "$path" ]; then
   "details of [$PWD] :" 
else
   echo "details of [$path] : "
fi
```

Let's say I'm running this script in this directory: **/home/root/mypath1/mypath2**

example when I run getpath.sh without argument:

```
./getpath.sh

output: details of /home/root/mypath1/mypath2
```

Then, when I run getpath.sh  script with an argument:

```
./getpath.sh /etc/nginx

output: details of /etc/nginx
```

The above results are ok but I want to get full path of the directory n-level up using '..'. 
Example when I run this script with '..' argument:

```
./getpath.sh ..

output: details of ..  
the expected output should be: details of /home/root/mypath1
```

Another one

```
./getpath.sh ../..

output: details of ..
the expected output should be: details of /home/root/
```

and the last example:

```
.getpath.sh ../../..

output: details of ..
the expected output should be: details of /home
```

What can I modify to make it work?

Comment: @KalibHozany : On Linux, you should already have `realpath` availabel. On the Mac you could have to install the GNU coreutils to get this utility. Another possibility would be to switch to Zsh, which has such a facility already built-in: `$path:A` would resolve to the absolute path.

Comment: I read all the link givens but most of the answers are not what I'm looking for. example the top answer asking to install extra packages: readlink  which I think is not related to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to cd "$path", if what the user passed in is a directory, and set the path to . if nothing is passed in.

```
#!/bin/bash
path="$1"

if [ -z "$path" ]; then
  path="."
fi

if [ -d "$path" ]; then
  cd "$path"
  path=$PWD
fi

echo "details of $path :"
```

Gives this output for me:

```
tmp$ ./getpath.sh
details of /mnt/c/Users/ianmc/tmp :
tmp$ ./getpath.sh ../..
details of /mnt/c/Users :
```

Comment: Thank you so much. @Ian McGowan